# My Basic Android App closes after splashscreen

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I have created a basic Android64 app, with just one button and managed to build it. After installing it on my device (sideloaded), I see the app in the startmenu but once I start it it shows a splashscreen and then closes. I never get to see the button...

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Main: TMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}

procedure TMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

What's wrong here? :-/

PS: I have noticed, that the form is not set to visible by default, and changed that (but no change). Is there a reason to it?

PS: Update 13042021: I found out this only happens on my OnePlus 8 Pro, but not on my Samsung S9. Weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android apps compiled with Delphi 10.3 may not run correctly on Android 10 and later due to a known issue on the IDE precompiled binaries. If it's the case -and I'm assuming this based on the symptoms described and the Android OS version your phones may be potentially running- you will find detailed instructions to patch your RAD Studio installation on the Embarcadero Quality Portal ([link](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27218?focusedCommentId=88179&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-88179)). You may need to create a free Embarcadero account to access the site if you don't have one yet.

Comment: This sounds promissing, thank you very much. I do have an account but wasn't able to sign in, I'll continue trying...

Comment: Glory to you, @Alex Guzman!
Thank you very much for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with 32Bits ?

Same behavior occurs with a datamodule and SQLlite connection active .

Comment: How does this answer the q?  I thnk it should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: there is no datamodule or SQLLite...
But I'll try still.

Comment: Doesnt change anything :-(

Comment: Can you tell more about your environment . Delphi version , device type and version , did you modified the manifest .

Comment: Delphi Version 10.3, see update 13042021 on mobile devices and a new mystery. I have bnot modified the amnifest - even the default "Tabbed Application" Template shows the same effects,